# Terminate active http calls when the user leaves the page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am building an app where I have several ui-router views and each view has its own data coming from http calls. How can I ensure to terminate all active http calls if the user leaves the current page and navigates to other view.

Comment: which version of angular are you using 1.x or 2.x/4.x ?

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović you should trust OP when they tag question "angularjs" :)

Comment: I am using angular1.x